# How to use MySQL's COUNT() correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get a listing of user id's (uid) that have posted more than 3 articles. Here's my sql:

```
SELECT n.uid
FROM node
GROUP BY n.uid
HAVING COUNT( n.type = 'article' ) > 3
```

After doing some reading, I'm guessing my mistake is with my usage of COUNT, but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Any hints? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More like...

```
SELECT uid
FROM node
WHERE type = 'article'
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(uid) > 3
```

**EDIT**: I'll add a bit more info on `WHERE` vs. `HAVING`. As far as I remember, `HAVING` is used to apply conditions post-aggregation by `GROUP BY`. `WHERE` is used to apply conditions to the table in general.

Answer (score 3):

```
HAVING COUNT( n.type = 'article' ) > 3
```

Why this doesn't work <sub>*(re: I can't find out what I'm doing wrong)*</sub>:

- `n.type = 'article'`  << this returns a BOOLEAN, which is either true/false or 1/0
- COUNT ( x ) increases the counter whenever x is NOT NULL
- **both** of 1/0 are not null, therefore, it counts ALL types, and is equivalent to COUNT(*)

You wanted (this answer has already been given, but repeating here)

```
SELECT n.uid
FROM node
WHERE n.type = 'article'
GROUP BY n.uid
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 3
```

In general you could also write your COUNT properly using CASE, but the WHERE filter is normally faster

```
SELECT n.uid
FROM node
GROUP BY n.uid
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN n.type = 'article' THEN 1 END ) > 3
```

Answer (score 1):

COUNT() can only count up grouped records or columns in grouped results; it can't be used to count records that meet a condition in the way you want. Try either subquerying the expression, or pulling it up into the select list where it can be used in conditions:

```
SELECT n.uid, COUNT(*)
FROM node n
WHERE n.type = 'article'
GROUP BY n.uid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3

SELECT n.uid
FROM node n
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) from node n2 where n2.uid = n.uid AND n.type == 'article')  > 3
```

Comment: -1 for `COUNT() can only evaluate column names, not conditions.` It **can** evaluate conditions, such as `COUNT(Case when .. then 1 else NULL end)`

Comment: ... which wasn't his usage to begin with; he wanted to use Count() in a similar way as .NET Linq, where it returns the number of elements for which a predicate is true. I'll clarify, but please remove your downvote.

Comment: When I actually downvote, I don't preface with -1 (not normally). -1 in sentiment only, but someone else carried it out. Your edit makes for a really bad query anyway. (the 2nd one, so not sure why it is offerred when the 1st is working, per other answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.id, COUNT(n.id) as my_count
FROM node
WHERE n.type = 'article'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING my_count > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.uid
FROM node n
--- keep only articles postings
WHERE n.type = 'article'
--- group by user
GROUP BY n.uid
--- count rows while grouping (you can use COUNT(*) instead, result is same)
HAVING COUNT( n.uid ) > 3
```

Because TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 in MySQL (as Richard explained), your query would work (!) by changing only `COUNT` to `SUM` :

```
SELECT n.uid
FROM node n
GROUP BY n.uid
HAVING SUM( n.type = 'article' ) > 3
```

But that is not the proper way to do this!